# Paypal Recurring Payments With Specific Months

Tags: php, paypal, recurring

I need to set-up to a paypal recurring payment to my client's website. The following condition should be met:
1. they can subscribe anytime in a year but they should only be billed during April, May, June and July
example: they will subscribe now, their first payment will still be on April 2015, then on May 2015, June 2015 and July 2015. After that, payments will stop. Then on April 2016, they will be billed again, and so with the next 3 months.

Is it possible when using Paypal API Recurring Payments SDK kit (CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile)?

I'm using PHP as a language.

Comment: I'm just going to suggest looking into Stripe instead of Paypal. Paypal is very controversial for the people on the receiving end of payments. Just a suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do this with paypal but you will need paypal pro account for that and it will only available for US,UK and canada and probably for australia for now.  you can visit following link

```
    https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-pro/integration-guide/WPRecurringPayments/

http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/10930/paypal-pro-creditcardtype-invalid-parameter
```

hope this help :)